# oracle sql group by change in time valid from valid to

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, row-number

I have following historical data regarding tickets status changes over time, thing I'm interested in is to have results with VALFROM-VALTO

The source data

```
ticket_ID, change-time        , queue
--------------------------------------
001      , 2018-01-01 00:00:00, queue1
001      , 2018-01-01 00:01:00, queue1
001      , 2018-01-01 00:03:00, queue2
001      , 2018-01-01 00:04:00, queue1
001      , 2018-01-01 00:05:00, queue3
```

The target data

```
ticket_ID, valfrom            , valto              , queue
-----------------------------------------------------------
001      , 2018-01-01 00:00:00, 2018-01-01 00:02:59, queue1
001      , 2018-01-01 00:03:00, 2018-01-01 00:03:59, queue2
001      , 2018-01-01 00:04:00, 2018-01-01 00:04:59, queue1
001      , 2018-01-01 00:05:00, 2999-12-31 23:59:59, queue3
```

I think this can be done using ROW_NUMBER function with OVER. 
Any useful advice is more than welcome.

Comment: look for gaps and islands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in various ways, here I used `lag()` to eliminate rows, where previous `change_time` is the same as current and used `lead()` to show next value as `valto`:

**<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/83b2cd/1434)</sup>**

```
select id, queue, ct valfrom, 
       nvl(lead(ct) over (order by ct) - interval '1' second, 
           date '3000-01-01' - interval '1' second) valto
  from (select id, ct, queue, lag(queue) over (order by ct) lq from source)
  where lq is null or lq <> queue
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a difference of row numbers approach to classify rows into groups (based on consecutive queue values being the same), `lead` to get values from the next row. Thereafter, it is a `group by` operation to get the from and to times.

```
select ticketid,queue,min(change_time),
coalesce(max(next_change_time)-interval '1' second,timestamp '2999-12-31 23:59:59')
from (select t.*,row_number() over(partition by ticketid order by change_time) 
                 -row_number() over(partition by ticketid,queue order by change_time) as grp,
      lead(change_time) over(partition by ticketid order by changetime) as next_change_time
      from tbl t 
     ) t
group by ticketid,queue,grp
```